# Html <select> go on top of page

Tags: html, select

I have problem with  tag. I create a simple page,without css file, jus to to show my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/c7nge/

Just find select field, try to select ,and all content go up, on top of page...

Crazy :)

Here is html code :

```
<

!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Depaco|Strap|Box|Analise</title></title>



</head>
<body>
<header>
<div class="container clearfix">
<p class="packing ">Depaco <span>Box</span></p>

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="curl-top-left">Depaco <span>Stretch</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="strap.php" class="curl-top-left">Depaco <span>Strap</span></a</li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="curl-top-left">Depaco <span>Box</span></a</li>
                    <li><a href="#" class="curl-top-left">Depaco <span>Analyse</span></a</li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Calculator</span></a</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
</div><!-- end containe -->
</header>
<div class="content clearfix">
<form>
<div class="container ">

<div class="left-box">
<p class="red">For theoretical compression strength of box, please fill all fields...</p>
<p class="grey">Depako box is a statistical method that gives the theoretical value of box compression strength. It applies to the RSC boxes.</p>
<div class="roki"><p class="text1-box">Characteristics of box</p></div>
<div class="box-box clearfix"> <!-- Box 1-->



<p class="text">Only for box without Inner carton (reinforcement) and
without laminating the box .</p>


</div><!-- END Box 1-->

</div><!-- end left -->

<div class="right-box">

<img src="" alt="Depako Box" Title="Depako Box" class="strap-img"></img></br></br>

    Here is problem: </br></br></br>

    <select>
<option value ="sydney">Sydney</option>
<option value ="melbourne">Melbourne</option>
<option value ="cromwell" selected>TRY</option>
<option value ="queenstown">Queenstown</option>
</select>

</br></br></br></br>
<p class="text">Technical requirements for theoretical of compression strength: </br></br>
Maximum dimension of box is: Lx Bx H= 550x 350x 350 mm</br></br>
Maximum grammage of corrugated fiberboard is: 900 g/m2</br></br>
For other cases, please contact us.</br>
</br></p></br></br>



</div><!-- end right -->


</form>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<footer>
<div id="footer">
<div id="logo">
<img src="images/logo.png" alt="DEPACO logo"></img>

</div><!-- end logo -->






</div>
</div><!-- end container2 -->
</footer>


</div><!-- end content -->


</div><!-- end container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Tnx, P

Comment: What's up with your doctype?

Comment: Surprising your `<select>` works fine.

Comment: The output on JS Fiddle alone should have pointed out that there was an improperly closed anchor tag.

Comment: Here is print screen in my Chrome :                       http://picpaste.com/test-YfkOsWYH.jpg

Comment: Because your entire page is a link, you click it and it refreshes the page. That moves it to the top.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should have a look at validating your HTML.
Your problem is this line:

```
<li><a href="#"><span>Calculator</span></a</li>
```

It should be:

```
<li><a href="#"><span>Calculator</span></a></li>
```

You never closed the `a` tag and therefor everything after it will be part of the link, also the `select` box.
So you are clicking on the link, not the `select` box.
A good way of overcoming these kinds of problems is using a good editor that will complete your code and highlights problems.

Another good way is to put your code in the http://validator.w3.org and check for errors there.

Comment: Tnx! </a> is a problem! Solved! Tnx for time!

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I see is that some of your `</a>` tags are cut off so they're just `</a`. Correcting that, it all works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Many of your tags are not closed correctly (i.e. `</a` instead of `</a>`), this fixes it: http://jsfiddle.net/c7nge/1/